# Named pipes and AuFS issues

Tags: linux, filesystems, named-pipes

I'm trying to set up two different filesystem contexts.

```
$ mkdir a b common
$ mkfifo common/fifo
$ sudo mount -t aufs -o br=common none a
$ sudo mount -t aufs -o br=common none b
```

If I write and read to the same fifo path (e.g `a/fifo`) everything works fine, but if I do

```
shell1$ cat a/fifo
...
shell2$ echo 'hi' > b/fifo
```

nothing happens.

Are the some additional options for `aufs` which would make this work, or am I hitting a more fundamental problem. Is there a different union FS I should look into (yes, in the actual context I stack other directory trees and tmpfs).